# how to check if an field is not filled out in ejs

Tags: discord, discord.js, dashboard

`https://pastebin.com/GxNe01LB`

Error:

`Error updating welcome channel: CastError: Cast to string failed for value "[ '', '' ]" (type Array) at path "welcomeChannel" at SchemaString.cast (C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\moxx handler\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:606:11) at SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\moxx handler\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1219:12) at SchemaString.castForQuery (C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\moxx handler\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:690:15) at castUpdateVal (C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\moxx handler\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:576:19) at walkUpdatePath (C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\moxx handler\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:381:24) at castUpdate (C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\moxx handler\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:110:7) at model.Query._castUpdate (C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\moxx handler\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4709:10) at model.Query._updateThunk (C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\moxx handler\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3876:25) at model.Query._updateOne (C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\moxx handler\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3964:23) at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\moxx handler\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4429:28) { stringValue:`"[ '', '' ]"`, messageFormat: undefined, kind: 'string', value: [ '', '' ], path: 'welcomeChannel', reason: null, valueType: 'Arr`ay'
}

> i try to check if the field is filed out but i dont know how because its dont work